# Dynamically Generating Datatables with dynamic columns and data

Tags: javascript, datatable

There are 2 buttons Companies and Stocks , i am trying to generate data table dynamically using the below steps :

1. When button gets clicked get the tab id / name and then pull data from backend and the column names
2. Check if the data table exits then destroy it and then create new and add the above data and column dynamically.  Using the below Code .

   ```
         <ul class="nav flex-column">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link active but" aria-current="page" href="" id="companies">
                        <span data-feather="home" class="align-text-bottom but"></span>
                        Companies
                      </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link  but" aria-current="page" href="" id="stocks">
                        <span data-feather="home" class="align-text-bottom but"></span>
                        Stocks
                      </a>
                    </li>
            </ul>


                $(".but").on("click", async function (e) {
                   e.preventDefault();
                   $(".content").hide();
                   $("#" + this.id + "div").show();
                   $('#title').text(this.id.toUpperCase());
                   tab = this.id ; 
                   $(this.id).addClass('active');
                   var tabData = await getDataSet(tab); 
                   var tabColumn =  getcolumnData(tab);
                   console.log(tabData);
                   console.log(tabColumn);

                   collectionRef = collection(db,collectionName+'_'+tab);
                   if(table !=null){
                     table.destroy();
                   }
                    table = $('#example').DataTable({
                   data: tabData,
                   columns:  tabColumn,
                   columnDefs: [
                     {
                         targets: -1,
                         data: null,
                         defaultContent: ' <button type="button"  id="delete" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Delete</button> <button type="button"  id="edit" class="btn btn-sm                   btn-outline-secondary">Edit</button>',
                     },
                 ],
                 });
                 });
   ```

But this is not working very fine , sometime when i am clicking on Companies/Stocks button randomly , sometimes the Datatable is empty , sometimes it works , sometimes there is no error but the page is blank . Not sure what is a better way to achieve this or destroy the datatables and recreate in a better way.